# How to write to function to check how long input from user is

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I need to write function to check if my number from user prompt number and if is he 13 charachers long.
My idea was to set 2 condition, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var num =parseInt(prompt("Write your number"));

if( typeof(num) ==="number" && num.length ==13){
console.log("It's number 13 chars long");
}
else{
console.log("It's not number or it's not 13 chars long");
}
```

If i use 2 separated condiotions its work :O
I dont know do that with regex cuz im am begginer :)

Comment: but how i can set that  var num must be numbers, not string or something else

Answer (score 0):

Your current `parseInt` doesn't do anything useful because it will always give something which is of type `number` in return, and numbers don't have a `.length`, so the `parseInt` results in the `num.length` check failing.

After turning the input into an integer, turn it back into a string and then all you need to do is check its length, because anything that *isn't* a well-formed number won't have 13 digits:

```js
const num = parseInt(prompt("Write your number"));

console.log(
  String(num).length == 13
    ? "It's number 13 chars long"
    : "It's not number or it's not 13 chars long"
);
```